# Prefixing a constant string to RegEx group

Tags: c#, regex

I am stuck at a simple problem.

I am using RegEx to extract url's from html markup. I want to add constant prefix

```
"The site is"
```

to the extracted RegEx group.

Sample markup:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="www.stackoverflow.com"></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the expression I am using is:

```
<a\shref="(?<Url>.*?)"></a>
```

Currenlty I am getting group Url as

```
www.stackoverflow.com
```

but I want that as

```
The site is www.stackoverflow.com
```

How can I get it?

Comment: Can't you simply concatenate "The site is " with group result value?

Comment: @Marco I thought that would be great if I can get it done in RegEx itself.

Comment: IMHO Regex should be used to extract values from a complex string using rules: presentation of the result is made after...

Comment: Similar to [Regex: Named Capturing Groups in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/906847/471214)

Comment: @mmdemirbas My question is not at all related to how to extract hrefs from anchors, I want to prefix some string to extracted RegEx group, not from code but in RegEx itself, hope you get it ! :)

Comment: Yes, I meant this: `link = regex.Match(input).Result("The site is ${Url}");`

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex  regex  = new Regex(@"<a\shref=""(?<Url>.*?)""></a>")
String input  = ... // your sample markup
String result = regex.Match(input).Result("The site is ${Url}");
```

Comment: The same I want to achieve with RegEx, I mean the RegEx match itself should give the result (what result in your snippet will contain) and not the C#.

Comment: As I know, this is impossible. Do you have any strong reason to want so? I am really wondering.

Comment: Actually, I am writing a small crawler, so some websites give absolute anchors with domain name included  (e.g. www.xyz.com/p/q.aspx) and some give relative anchors (e.g /p/q.aspx). So in case of relative ones, I am thinking to obtain absolute hyperlinks (i.e. with domain name included). :)

Comment: Ok, you should use C# with regex. Bare regex will disappoint you at this point.

Comment: actually, I was thinking C# as the last resort, thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1):

Brief answer: don't parse HTML using regex. [In depth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Even if your suggestion is correct, it doesn't solve OP question. Maybe this should be a comment...

Comment: The answer is "don't do it" -- the same as the correct answer for the linked question.

Comment: No, then answer is not that, but it's my opinion. I try to explain what I mean. OP wants to extract an URL from a webpage and then wants to have "The site is " concatenated with that url. It doesn't matter (here) how OP extracts that url (Regex, HtmlAgilityPack or anything else), he has to join these two strings in some way. Even if OP decides to use HtmlAgilityPack (born exactly to accomplish these kinds of tasks) he has to concatenate strings after extraction. Do you agree?

Comment: Perhaps something along [these lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122856/parse-html-links-using-c-sharp)?

Comment: Using regex in this example perfectly valid. He doesn't do any **parsing** (extracting doesn't count). He does **extract** text after `<a href="` strings whereever, and I think he is happy with this.

Comment: `<a title="Link title" href="`

Comment: Actually, I would prefer to search for `href=` instead of `<a href=`, but OP seems sure that `href` always comes as first attribute in their samples (so, I meant that with `I think he is happy with this`).

Comment: `<base href="...`. There's always going to be caveats. :(

Comment: It is also a link technically :)